# Xamarin Forms sending mail from app directly

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In `Xamarin` forms I want to sent email directly from app without opening email client. I want user to type in text and just send it with predefined subject to predefined email address. I need implementation for `IOS` and `Android`. Is it possible to do within share project in `Xamarin` forms?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is a UI Framework it doesn't send e-mails...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask yourself if that really is the best approach, I think it would be better to have some call to your back-end and have that send it for you.

But I'm not the one to judge your requirements, so if I'm just looking for a solution why not setup a SendGrid account (free up til a whole bunch of mails in [Azure](https://sendgrid.com/partners/azure/)) and use the [SendGrid API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) (easily accessible through a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid)) to send your mail. There are probably some more alternatives like this out there.